# Formatting a string variable in discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots, markdown

In my current discord bot, I want my program to output everything in the same format:

```py
@client.command()
async def audios(ctx):
    # audio is a link from a list of links i have stored in all_audios
    audio = random.choice(all_audios)
    audiostr = str(audio)
    # this queries a part of the link
    output = PurePosixPath(
        unquote(
            urlparse(audiostr).path
        )     
    ).parts[1]
    actualoutput = str(output)
    await ctx.send("`credits to `" + actualoutput + "\n" + audio)
```

Is it possible to make the `actualoutput` formatted with the backticks  ?
When I run this command via discord, it returns

`credits to` text

[www.example.com](http://www.example.com)

I want it to return as

`credits to text`

[www.example.com](http://www.example.com)

Everything works fine, I would just prefer if the formatting could all match. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you explicitly explain what's wrong, and how you want your output to look like ?

Comment: I just edited the original post, let me know if there's more information I should add.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move your closing backtick to the end of your string before the line break like this :

```
await ctx.send("`credits to " + actualoutput + "`\n" + audio)
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: @yu1612 You’re welcome! If this answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Comment: Will do! I'm fairly new to stackoverflow, so I wasn't aware of that. Thank you for letting me know!

Answer (score 0):

I misunderstood the question. If you want the format on the `actualoutput` as well, you can move he backticks to the end.

So instead it should be:

```py
await ctx.send("`credits to " + actualoutput + "`\n" + audio)
```

It results in: `credits to <actualoutput>`

Comment: No worries at all :)